# Can't bind to 'data-intro' since it isn't a known property of 'button'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, intro.js

I am using intro.js library in angular 8. Everything working fine, but on this step I am stuck.
I am not able to bind value in data-intro in this button tag. Actually "introForShowHide" is basically a text which i send from my component.ts file.

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue, how i can bind value in data-intro.

`<button type="button"  data-step="1" [data-intro]="introForShowHide" data-position="right">Demo </button>`

Comment: Can anyone help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1):

write like that

```
<button type="button"(click)="howResourceDescription()"  data-step="1"[attr.data-intro]="introForShowHide"  data-position="right">Demo </button>
```

put your function into its component.ts

```
howResourceDescription() { 
    this.introForShowHide = "Click on hide instructions button to hide instructions displayed corresponding to enabling each resource type." 
 }
```

Comment: I had tired this also but getting same error message 

Can't bind to 'intro' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

Comment: <button type="button" id="step4" data-step="1" attr.data-intro={{introForShowHide}} data-position="right" class="btn" (click)="showResourceDescription()">Demo</button>



I have add  this  [attr.data-intro]="introForShowHide" but the problem is this when I click on this button then introduction text must be changed which i am changing after calling this  showResourceDescription() function.

Comment: Every time it only show the text which is fixed or remain unchanged after calling this  showResourceDescription() function. The purpose of using binding is to change the text when I call this function showResourceDescription().

Comment: Put your function that changes text im question

Comment: // Before constructor when declare this variable 

`introForShowHide = "You can click on Show Instructions button to see action corresponding to enabling each resource";`

// After calling showResourceDescription() function

`showResourceDescription() {
this.introForShowHide = "Click on hide instructions button to hide instructions displayed corresponding to enabling each resource type."
}`

Comment: Hi,
It is not changing any text. Please use intro.js library, it show step 1 with initial data-intro value but when i click on this button then data-intro must be changed.

Comment: Bu there is no click event in this button. If u want to fire your action by clicking this button then u need to ad click event. I edited answer

Comment: `<button type="button" data-step="1" [attr.data-intro]="introForShowHide" data-position="right"  (click)="showResourceDescription()">Demo</button>`

I am using click event without using click event how I can call a function.

Comment: put your function to your component.ts

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tslbv u can check here where function is

Comment: Hi Cagri,

ofcourse this function is in its component.ts file.

`showResourceDescription() { 
this.introForShowHide = "Click on hide instructions button to hidee."
 }`

Comment: I added also Demo2 button which is not using click event. It is using dom js to detect click u can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5tslbv again to see it

Comment: Thak you Cagri !!